# RGTK2 gtkcombo: get current selected text

Tags: r, gtk

I want to create dropdown list in R using `RGtk2`. I used the following code:

```
items <- c("First Item", "Second Item", "Third Item", "Fourth Item",
       "Fifth Item")
combo <- gtkCombo()
combo$setPopdownStrings(items)
```

Now, how can I get the current selected item? `gtkcombobox` has a method `gtkComboBoxGetActiveText(object)`. Is there any thing for `gtkCombo`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the warning :

**WARNING: GtkCombo has been deprecated since version 2.4 and should not be used in newly-written code. Use GtkComboBox instead.**

Assuming you are aware of this , you can set the `entry` of your combo and read its text property :

```
x <- combo$entry
print(x$text)
[1] "First Item"
```

Comment: Hi agstudy, thank you for your response. I think I am going to use gtkComboBoxText. Is there any way to remove all items or get the get the no of items in the list?